# How to change the foreground of the header text of a WPF tabitem onClick?

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, controltemplate, tabitem

How can I change only the foreground color of a `TabItem` header text when it is selected or active without changing the foreground of any item inside that `TabItem`or anything? I'm new to all this so finding it difficult to figure out where in my `TabItem`styling can I implement this little feature and how.

The `TabControl` style I'm using is:

```
<Style
    x:Key="{x:Type TabControl}"
    TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter
        Property="BorderThickness"
        Value="0" />
    <Setter
        Property="BorderBrush"
        Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter
        Property="Background"
        Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter
        Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate
                TargetType="TabControl">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition
                            Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition
                            Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border
                        BorderThickness="0,0,1,1"
                        BorderBrush="#D0CEBF"
                        Grid.Row="1">
                        <Border
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                            <Border
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <TabPanel
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        IsItemsHost="true"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style
    TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter
        Property="BorderThickness"
        Value="0" />
    <Setter
        Property="BorderBrush"
        Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter
        Property="Background"
        Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter
        Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
        Value="Center" />
    <Setter
        Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
        Value="Center" />
    <Setter
        Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate
                TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <!--In order to click on the blank part of the TabItem can be successfully selected-->
                <Border
                    Background="Transparent">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid
                            x:Name="g">
                            <Path
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Margin="0,0,0,-1"
                                Data="M 20,40 L 0,40 0,40 C 4,40 10,36 10,30 L 10,10 C 10,0 16,0 20,0 L 155,0  C 165,0 173,0 ,175,6 L175,30 C 175,30 175,38 182,40 Z" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Border
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <!--Add ControlTemplate.Triggers to change the background color of the selected TabItem.-->
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger
                        Property="IsSelected"
                        Value="false">
                        <Setter
                            Property="Visibility"
                            TargetName="g"
                            Value="Hidden" />
                    </Trigger>
                
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a trigger in your `TabItem` control template unfortunately sets the foreground color of the `TabItem` content, too, when the tab is selected, so this does not work.

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</Trigger>
```

However, you could add an implicit `TextBlock` style (without `x:Key`) inside the `ContentPresenter` resources. It will be applied automatically only to `TextBlock`s inside of its scope, not affecting the `TabItem` content or even other elements in a custom header template other than `TextBlock`s.

```
<ContentPresenter
    ContentSource="Header"
    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" >
   <ContentPresenter.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
               Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}"
               Value="true">
               <Setter
                  Property="Foreground"
                  Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Alternatively, a specialized solution is to create a header template and put the trigger there. In this case it does not force an overridden header template to apply the foreground to each `TextBlock`.

```
<Setter
    Property="HeaderTemplate">
   <Setter.Value>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
            <TextBlock.Style>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                  <Style.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}"
                        Value="true">
                        <Setter
                           Property="Foreground"
                           Value="Red" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
         </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried this before posting this question and it wasn't working... turns out as I was giving a `Foreground` color inside the window `<Tabitem ...>` it was always showing that color. After removing that it works as expected.

Comment: BTW, I had a `textblock` inside that `Tabitem` and its `Foreground` color was also changing, so do I have to set a `Foreground` color for every control/item inside a `tabitem`? I only wanted to change the Header text color. Is that even possible?

Comment: @Jayanta_KMC Yes, your are right, the original solution affected the `TabItem` content, too. I have replaced it with two other approaches that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I basically want to set a specific `Foreground` color say `Red` only to the `<Tabitem Header="..." ....>` portion when its selected/active. All the controls like `label, TextBlock, Datagrid, ...` etc their `Foreground` color should not change. How can I do that ? Should the second approach i.e. `<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">` one suffice ? Where can I put that code in my `Tabcontrol` style ?

Comment: @Jayanta_KMC You should use either the approach with `ContentPresenter` or the custom header template. Both only target the header, **not the tab content**. The tab default item header template is just a `TextBlock`. Of yourse if you have a custom header template that contains other controls which in turn contain `TextBlock`s then the `ContentPresenter` approach affects them, too. In that case just apply the style of the second approach to the one `TextBlock` inside the header template that you want.

Comment: In the second approach, you simply put that `Setter` directly inside the `<Style TargetType="TabItem">` style beside the other setters.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  I've also added a `Setter` for `Property="FontWeight"` as well below the `<Setter Property="Foreground" ...` and it seems to work as well. Hope there won't be any issues !